# Calculating the median number of points scored by a team?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Teams  Points Fouls
TeamA  12     4 
TeamA  14     6 
TeamB  25     9
TeamB  27     11
TeamB  29     13 
TeamA  16     15  
TeamA  18     7 

def pointsmedian(points):
    df = pd.DataFrame(points)
    median_points = df[(df['Teams'] == 'TeamA') & (df['Points'])].median()
    return median_points
```

I am looking to return only the median for the number of points scored by team A, however, my code is returning the median number of fouls as well. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
df.groupby('Teams')['Points'].median()

Teams
TeamA    15
TeamB    27
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

If you want to get just for teamA, you can use `loc`on your `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('Teams',as_index=False)['Points'].median().set_index('Teams').loc['TeamA']

Out[397]: 
Points    15
Name: TeamA, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it definitely worked for me, I am also looking to compare the median points between two teams but when I assign the statement df.groupby('Teams',as_index=False)['Points'].median().set_index('Teams').loc['TeamA'] to a variable and compared the two variables for TeamA and TeamB, it returned an error. How can I use the number obtained by your method for comparison with other values?

Comment: So basically, let say I got the median for TeamA to be 15 and TeamB to be 27, I want to compare these two to see which one is greater. However, what I tried to do was assign TeamA_median =df.groupby('Teams',as_index=False)['Points'].median().set_index('Teams').loc['TeamA'], etc. and then compare which returned an error. Did that clarify it for you?

Comment: I understand what you need. You can go on from here.```df.groupby('Teams',as_index=False)['Points'].median().T.reset_index()```